# SQL questions for selecting correct data

Tags: sql

I have the below code

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT kit_color.color_id, color.color_name FROM kit_color
LEFT JOIN color ON kit_color.color_id = color.color_id
WHERE kit_color.id = %s
SQL;
return sprintf($sql, self::quote($id));
```

The table data is like

```
Table  "product_color"
Column1 "color_id"
Column2 "product_id"

Table "kit_color"
Column1 "id"
Column2 "color_id"

Table "color"
Column1 "color_id"
Column2 "color_name"
```

Example data

`product_color, as-1, 86501`

I am able to use the `color_id`, but I need the `product_id` from that `color_id`that is being displayed.  How can I do that?

I added the other table that is present. with the above code, everything works I just can display the product_color.product_id as it seems the info is not being pulled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT PC.product_id, KC.color_id, C.color_name 
FROM kit_color as KC
LEFT JOIN color as C
ON KC.color_id = C.color_id
LEFT JOIN product_color as PC
ON PC.color_id = C.color_id
WHERE KC.id = %s
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, this is the only one I tried that gets any results, The only issue is it starts poplating the page with duplicating results. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: Nevermind the above code did work and the duplicates are due to something eles. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this...

```
SELECT product_color.product_id, kit_color.color_id, color.color_name FROM kit_color
LEFT JOIN color ON kit_color.color_id = color.color_id
LEFT JOIN product_color ON product_color.color_id = color.color_id
WHERE kit_color.id = %s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement doesn't include the product_id in the select portion. It also doesn't match the table data as described. Using the table data you provided, if you have the kit_color.id, then you should be able to get the product_id like so:

```
SELECT product_color.product_id 
FROM kit_color 
JOIN product_color ON   
kit_color.color_id=product_color.color_id 
WHERE kit_color.id=[the_id_you_have]
```